# Perform sum in multiple select

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an insert like

```
 INSERT INTO Design
    (
        ....
        , [Folio]
        ....
    )
         SELECT
              ...
             , (SELECT TOP 1 MAX(Folio) + 1
                 FROM [Design])
               FROM @Table
```

So, that insert is for multiple rows, my select have more than 1 row.

My table `Design` has a column called `Folio` and I want to get last folio inserted and sum + 1 for each row, so I tried using that subquery. But it just use same Folio always. I.E

If last folio is 1000 and rows to be inserted are 3
it insert folio 1001 in 3 rows instead 1001, 1002,1003.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: to be clear.. you would like to insert rows from a certain range right? say if you wanted 1000, therefore insert from 1001 to the last number?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to declare a variable which stores the last inserted Folio number and you need to add +1 on that variable before insert statement.
Hope this will work for you.

Comment: Same result, it just create same number